# xslt inserting cdata

Tags: xslt, cdata

i need to insert values of several  elements into one cdata... here is my code:

first, i made output:

```
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" intend="yes" cdata-section-elements="embassy" />
```

and here is element definition:

```
<xsl:element name="embassy">
  <xsl:value-of select="Visa/visa_velv/visa_velv_name" />
  <xsl:element name="br" />
  <xsl:value-of select="Visa/visa_velv/visa_velv_address" />
  <xsl:element name="br" />
  <xsl:value-of select="Visa/visa_velv/visa_velv_city" />
</xsl:element>
```

and here is bad output for my need:

```
<embassy><![CDATA[Ambasada e Republikes se Cekise]]>
  <br/><![CDATA[Rruga Skënderbej 10]]>
  <br/><![CDATA[Tirana]]>            
</embassy>
```

i need this output:

```
<embassy>
  <![CDATA[Ambasada e Republikes se Cekise<br/>Rruga Skënderbej 10<br/>Tirana]]>
</embassy>
```

i was reading [documentation](http://www.xm.co.nz/ShoXS/xsloutput.htm) but i can't find solution. thanks for helping :)

Comment: Why do you think you *need* CDATA?  It is usually a code smell, and often an indicator that people are not using XML APIs properly and relying on CDATA as a hack to avoid parsing errors.

Comment: I am making XSL transformation for OpenCMS. Every data in element must be in cdata element. I thing that it must be beacuse there is no good documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This complete and simple transformation:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" cdata-section-elements="Embassy"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="visa_velv">
     <Embassy>
       <xsl:value-of select=
       "concat(visa_velv_name,'&lt;br/>',visa_velv_address,'&lt;br/>',visa_velv_city)"/>
     </Embassy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the folowing XML document:**

```
<Visa>
 <visa_velv>
   <visa_velv_name>Ambasada e Republikes se Cekise</visa_velv_name>
   <visa_velv_address>Rruga Skënderbej 10</visa_velv_address>
   <visa_velv_city>Tirana</visa_velv_city>
 </visa_velv>
</Visa>
```

**produces the wanted result:**

```
<Embassy><![CDATA[Ambasada e Republikes se Cekise<br/>Rruga Skënderbej 10<br/>Tirana]]></Embassy>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really need or want to escape markup then use

```
<embassy>
  <xsl:value-of select="Visa/visa_velv/visa_velv_name" /><![CDATA[<br/>]]><xsl:value-of select="Visa/visa_velv/visa_velv_address" /><![CDATA[<br/>]]><xsl:value-of select="Visa/visa_velv/visa_velv_city" />
</embassy>
```

and of course the `cdata-section-elements="embassy"` you already have.